# Unable to set 'failurePolicy: Fail' for ExternalAdmissionHookConfiguration

Tags: kubernetes

On Kubernetes 1.7, I am trying to create an ExternalAdmissionHookConfiguration. I have tried to set the `failurePolicy: Fail`, however, I get the following error:

```
The ExternalAdmissionHookConfiguration "policy-agent" is invalid: externalAdmissionHooks[0].failurePolicy: Unsupported value: "Fail": supported values: Ignore
```

The documentation suggests that `Fail` is a valid option.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/extensible-admission-controllers/

Comment: Note: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blame/2db28383e1151e5d442b81eb73a02b3cf144615c/pkg/apis/admissionregistration/validation/validation_test.go#L488-L498, https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/commit/9ddea83a2ce0937cf0fc8f8c35614bb18e74cfad. Nite sure Fail was supported  back then.

Answer (score 0):

It is valid as of 1.9

I'd recommend building on 1.9 admission webhooks. The pre-1.9 versions were discontinued at alpha level and redone as validating and mutating versions in 1.9